# No puedo cargar mi app en el iPhone

Tags: swift2, xcode, iphone

No se que ha sucedido pero me tira el siguiente error, he intentado todo, pero de un momento a otro se desconfiguro y ya no me funciona enviar mi app al iPhone :(

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora me dice lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y cuando voy al llavero me dice:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sucedió que mi PC se reinicio y cambio la fecha y ahora al año 2000, pero ajuste la hora y esta bien pero sigue lo mismo.

Después me funciono compilar, al eliminar el certificado, apagar el PC, elimine todas las app de la web de Apple y después al final funciono por arte de magia. xD

Pero me dio este error:

```
  dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/3FC2DC5C-A908-42C4-8508-1320E01E0D5B/Stylist.app/Stylist
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/3FC2DC5C-A908-42C4-8508-1320E01E0D5B/testapp.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib: mmap() errno=1 validating first page of '/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/3FC2DC5C-A908-42C4-8508-1320E01E0D5B/testapp.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib'
(lldb)
```

Y según [este post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32730312/reason-no-suitable-image-found/32730393#32730393), la solución es así y me funciono:

```
rm -rf "$(getconf DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR)/org.llvm.clang/ModuleCache"
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode
```

Comment: No se nada de IOS pero según el mensaje dice que si tienes el certificado pero no está instalado, ¿Lo tienes instalado?

Comment: Sí, está instalado.

Comment: ¿Y si intentas agregar de nuevo tu apple ID? `preferences>Accounts>Selecciona tu Apple ID>quítalo(-)>agrégalo de nuevo(+)` o bien reiniciar XCode ._.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elimina los certificados relacionados y los provisioning, tanto en local como en la cuenta de developer. No te preocupes que no dejarán de funcionar tus apps.
Una vez borrados, vuélvelos a generar de nuevo y listo.

Answer (score 1):

Primeramente, los certificados de seguridad requieren que tengas la fecha y hora correctas.

> please verify that your device’s clock is properly set

Elimina los certificados y genera nuevos.